# What is a good way to capture task_struct values on every context switch?

Tags: linux, kernel-modules

I want to collect a list of values from the task_struct of a specific process (I know its name) on every context switch. What is a good method to achieve this?

Comment: I don't know if you will get the **best** way. Can you tell us why? What are you trying to find out? What is going wrong?

Comment: Are you using/able to use gdb on the kernel?

Comment: I need the data to train a neural network. Right now i have a module to pass the process name of interest and deliver the result to the use space through /proc files. I modified the context switch function to collect the task_struct info and pass it to my module.  I'm currently missing a bunch of task_struct records as if my function is not being called every time from the context switch function.